# Open a BufferedReader in UTF-8

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, bufferedreader, oracle12c

I have a csv file with characters like `Cité`, but after make the insert into the DB, I see this `Cit¿`

I open the file as a `BufferedReader`, but I don't know how to do it in `UTF-8`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html) if helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* explictly use a `FileInputStream` and an `InputStreamReader` using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, but it's probably simpler to use [`Files.newBufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
Path path = Paths.get(csvFile);
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    // Use the reader
}
```

It's worth getting to know the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class as it has a bunch of convenience methods like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FileInputStream`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```